# Grafico de colunas de um Data Frame usando GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Tenho esse data.frame:

```
         A          K1            B         K2            C         K3          D          K4           E          K5
1   0.89386498 0.239258200 -0.004970278 0.99477685 -0.243845617 0.80370370  0.3132989 0.637155451 -0.55467576 0.049341476
2   0.35422172 0.681622485  0.370412512 0.16307651  0.120218788 0.70553119 -0.3785706 0.620439589 -0.53585345 0.512866264
3  -0.08822473 0.805475846  0.390890650 0.29180578 -0.130491618 0.82179688 -0.2968170 0.640475991  0.33332878 0.339335108
4  -0.19879373 0.515563149  0.329986403 0.43023779  0.605394833 0.27837442 -1.0011508 0.016018310  0.02337509 0.963839055
5  -0.37221704 0.419104636  0.392950076 0.38558719  0.188084913 0.66849304 -0.5266032 0.218914485 -0.32085498 0.500405641
6  -0.20459475 0.692386452  0.568645830 0.17021608  0.288753849 0.49383848 -0.4545543 0.337171364 -0.60244756 0.248371296
7  -0.45186425 0.472505247  0.663551684 0.06581302 -0.003074286 0.99493727 -0.4032701 0.414815932 -0.65511972 0.186299285
8  -0.51982456 0.415916983  0.471062125 0.24394765 -0.107008013 0.84106575 -0.7563691 0.147773780 -0.84926594 0.009802960
9  -0.46964248 0.458192402  0.355476072 0.44302317  0.005446758 0.99126679 -0.7926341 0.088187750 -0.92206557 0.003943399
10 -0.57979144 0.281139835 -0.255960402 0.54625757  0.019724061 0.95708759 -0.6752567 0.078041276 -0.89841963 0.022430270
11 -0.74374709 0.126643360 -0.032724654 0.93439114  0.016855827 0.96086308 -0.6766646 0.068679510 -0.40618630 0.323834865
12 -0.70151564 0.145157140 -0.077944864 0.86492576 -0.200596345 0.59040449 -0.5285331 0.160347843 -0.68089255 0.088859040
13 -0.63874335 0.163899016 -0.305108667 0.54415109 -0.436390952 0.36458650 -0.5594600 0.158095712 -0.58631642 0.093423291
14 -0.63371325 0.098193121 -0.145859650 0.76521523 -0.246842706 0.59664340 -1.0680730 0.013981482 -0.64035207 0.125937665
15 -0.89770765 0.046781142  0.096380430 0.78955195 -0.422087415 0.27930399 -1.0039011 0.053317646 -0.81908331 0.100781670
16 -0.97319036 0.048590205 -0.282556945 0.47673512 -0.529426213 0.13794864 -1.0362239 0.029096910 -0.86847177 0.176709263
17 -1.30573010 0.009399461 -0.755178838 0.12383659 -0.477216314 0.03947335 -0.7931716 0.037584830 -1.75022084 0.013850673
18 -1.26220009 0.001807917 -1.530479237 0.01114763 -0.337784624 0.22341312 -1.1027691 0.006180464 -2.09816576 0.001559422
19 -2.40348955 0.004009389 -1.014658994 0.25041707 -0.185155321 0.74738865 -1.4236772 0.051285205 -1.86782841 0.051609695
```

Quero plot gráficos separados para A,B,C,D e E condicionados a suas colunas.

Ou seja, Um gráfico para A condicionado a K1 e etc.

Só que eu gostaria de que os pontos no gráfico ficassem diferenciados, ou seja, sempre que um valor de K1 for menor do que 0.05 seria um asterisko quando for maior, uma bola.

Como faço isso?

Usando plot eu consegui + ou -. Mas usando ggplot não tenho muita ideia.

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código a seguir deve fazer o que você precisa:

```
df_long <- plyr::ldply(1:5, function(i){
  aux <- df[,(2*i -1):(2*i)]
  names(aux) <- c("valor_letra", "valor_k")
  aux$letra <- LETTERS[i]
  aux$K <- i
  aux
})
df_long$K_menor <- ifelse(df_long$valor_k < 0.05, "menor", "maior")

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = valor_letra, y = valor_k, shape = K_menor)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~letra)
```

O meu código primeiro [tranforma o seu data.frame em formato long](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), que é o melhor formato para ser consumido pelo `ggplot2`. Em seguida ele cria uma variável que indica se valor de K é menor do que `0.05`.

Logo depois ele faz o gráfico. No caso ele está usando triângulo e ponto. Você pode alterar isso facilmente no ggplot somando uma escala de shape (`scale_shape_manual`).

Exemplo `+ scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 5))` no gráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

A lista completa de shapes está aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Começando do zero e o sentido é de cima para baixo e da esquerda para a direita.

Comment: Valeu, demais Daniel!